# Is there a way to disable or hide output thrown by FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I went through the documentation but couldn't find a solution. I'm hoping there is some kind of argument that will tell `FFmpeg` to not show the output in the console.

The output that I'm referring to is in the screenshot given below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using simple command-line redirection like `ffmpeg args >NUL`? Although that may be a problem if it's waiting for input from the console...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two possibilities to either vastly reduce the amount of output, or redirect it to somewhere else.

1. From [ffmpeg manual](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): Run `ffmpeg` with the `-loglevel quiet` option.
2. Do what @martineau said and redirect it to a null file descriptor. FFmpeg outputs to stderr by default, so in Windows you'd do `ffmpeg ... 2>NUL`; on Cygwin or Linux/OS X/BSD, you'd do `ffmpeg ... 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: ffmpeg sends all of its text to stderr, so you need to use `ffmpeg ... 2> /dev/null` or `ffmpeg ... 2>NUL`

Comment: The redirection doesn't work because this garbage tries to do something interactively with stderr, and hangs if you redirect it.

Answer (score 18):

As per the other answer, `-loglevel quiet` supresses everything. But, sometimes it's useful to retain *some* output. Here are some other options:

- You can suppress report printing (the lines beginning with *frame=* that are output every few frames) by adding the `-nostats` option to your command line.
- You can suppress the banner (copyright notice, libraries, etc) by adding the `-hide_banner` option to your command line.

There are other options, see [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for details.

Comment: I used `-loglevel quiet -stats` to show only the `frame=` line. `-hide_banner` didn't work, or maybe with my setup what it did remove was not enough (there was still a page and a half of stuff before the `frame=` line).